# kubeadm init fails with incorrect docker version

Tags: docker, kubernetes

After installation of docker 17.09 and kubernetes 1.5 components. After the installation when tried to initiate kubeadm --init it throws below error.

```
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
```

DOCKER_VERSION: 17.09.0-ce
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    unsupported docker version: 17.09.0-ce

kubeadm-1.6.0-0.alpha.0.2074.a092d8e0f95f52.x86_64

What will be correct docker version to use now. Where can I download latest kubernetes packages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Kubernetes        Docker
-----------------------------------------------------------
1.2             
                1.9.1 is officially recommended. Docker v1.8.3 and Docker v1.10 are supported. 
                If you are using an older release of Docker, please upgrade. Known issues with Docker 1.9.1

1.3             
                The following versions of Docker Engine are supported - v1.10, v1.11 
                Although v1.9 is still compatible, we recommend upgrading to one of the supported versions. All prior versions of docker will not be supported.
1.4             
                If you are using Kubernetes to manage docker containers, please be aware Kubernetes has been validated to work with docker 1.9.1, docker 1.11.2 (#23397), and docker 1.12.0 (#28698)
1.5
                1.10.3 - 1.12.3, Docker versions as old as may 1.9.1 work with known issues but this is not guaranteed
1.6             
                1.10.3, 1.11.2, 1.12.6 validated, 1.9.x and the belows support removed starting from Kubernetes v1.6.0-beta.2
1.7             
                1.10.3, 1.11.2, 1.12.6 validated
1.8             
                1.11.2, 1.12.6, 1.13.1, 17.03.2 validated
1.9             
                1.11.2 - 1.13.1, 17.03.x validated
1.10            
                minimum supported version is 1.11, 1.11.2 to 1.13.1 and 17.03.x validated
1.11            
                1.11.2 to 1.13.1 and 17.03.x (ref)
1.12            
                1.11.1, 1.12.1, 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06.
1.13
                1.11.1, 1.12.1, 1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06 
1.14
                1.13.1, 17.03, 17.06, 17.09, 18.06, 18.09.
1.15
                kubeadm: bump the minimum supported Docker version to 1.13.1
                (no external dependencies info at the moment)


-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The source of information:

- 1.2 [Action required](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.2.md#action-required-1)
- 1.3 [Known Issues and Important Steps before Upgrading](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.3.md#known-issues-and-important-steps-before-upgrading)
- 1.4 [Action Required Before Upgrading](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.4.md#action-required-before-upgrading)
- 1.5 [External Dependency Version Information](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.5.md#external-dependency-version-information)
- 1.6 [Node components](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.6.md#node-components), [External Dependency Version Information](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.6.md#external-dependency-version-information)
- 1.7 [External Dependency Version Information](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.7.md#external-dependency-version-information)
- 1.8 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.8.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.9 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.9.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.10 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.10.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.11 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.11.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.12 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.12.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.13 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.13.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.14 [External Dependencies](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#external-dependencies)
- 1.15 [Changelog since v1.15.0-alpha.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#other-notable-changes-1)